# Use Netcat from script (without logging into destination)

Tags: ssh, backup, netcat

I have a backup method setup for all my Unix devices in the home to tar|pv|pigz|nc to a local server. As I've seen from numerous examples they all have you first have the destination machine listening to a port (either while physically at the machine or via ssh, for example)

`nc -w 60 -l 19001 > /dir/to/backup.tgz`

Then begin sending the stream from the current machine

`tar -cpf - /dir/to/backup | pv | pigz | nc -w 10 dest.i.p.addr 19001`

I am attempting to script this to avoid having to have multiple terminals open on the host machine during this process and make it almost one-click.  Typically sending a command over ssh to execute would be

`ssh -f user@dest.i.p.addr "nc -w 60 -l 19001 > /dir/to/backup.tgz"`

But while the port is open and the data is being transferred & accepted the backup.tgz file does not get populated: always reads as empty. Which leads me to believe sending the command via ssh in one line does not keep the listening port open.

Is there another route I am not seeing, or will I always need to log into the destination machine to create a listen session?

Comment: If you have to authenticate via ssh anyway, why not use [rsync](https://www.howtogeek.com/135533/how-to-use-rsync-to-backup-your-data-on-linux/)?

Comment: I use an ssh-key to authenticate so sending a command is no issue. My original method is rsync + ssh with a crontab to run weekly on the small <64gb devices. For my >64gb machines any data transfer over ssh connection is much too time consuming so I use netcat. Hope to make weekly backups of these machines, too.

Comment: If you run `rsyncd` on the destination host and sync with the `rsync://` protocol, the transfer will be unencrypted and may be comparable to or faster than `netcat` speeds. Ref: https://icesquare.com/wordpress/how-to-improve-rsync-performance/